# Probability with a die

Tags: probability

I roll a die repeatedly. Find the chance that the first 4 rolls all show different faces, and the 5th roll shows a face that has appeared before.

$P($First 4 rolls shows different faces$)=\frac{5}{6}\times \frac{4}{5}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{2}{3}=?$

$P($5th face appeared before$)=\frac{5}{6}?$

Product Rule= $P($First 4 roles$)\times P($5th Face$)=(\frac{5}{6})^2\times \frac{4}{5}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{2}{3}=?$

Comment: Parentheses, please.  You have many divides and multiplies, please make sure we know what is on top and what is on the bottom.

Comment: IMO, computing probabilities is an exercise in organization moreso than anything else. Explain what you trying to do in your calculation. It may help to do one step at a time rather than all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

First, how many outcomes exist to get four different numbers?

1. The first roll can have $6$ different outcomes, the second one should have $5$ and the third, and fourth?
2. What is the size of the sample space? (each time there exists $6$ possibilities.)
3. The fifth roll should be among those first four rolls so has $4$ possible outcomes so the probability is $4/6.$

Comment: This helped OP, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

(1) * (5/6) * (4/6) * (3/6) * (4/6)

The probability on the first roll is any roll, so it's one.

The probability on the second roll is the probability of it being any 1 of the 5 not yet seen faces, which is 5* (1/6)

The probability on the third roll is the probability of it being any 1 of the 4 not yet seen faces, which is 4*(1/6)

The probability on the fourth roll is the probability of it being any 1 of the 3 not yet seen faces, which is 3*(1/6)

The probability on the fith roll is the probability of it being any of the 4 already seen faces, which is 4*(1/6)

Comment: Jatorious understood!

Comment: I think this helped OP, so +1.  Sorry you didn't get the checkmark.  It happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for two rolls, the chance is $\frac 56$ that the second is not the same as the first.  Given that, what is the chance that the third roll is different from either of the first two?

Comment: Explain the conditional probability scheme hinted in Principle?

Comment: Thanks Ross Milikan got it!